# Error converting data, invalid type for parameter: 2 in Redshift

Tags: mysql, pentaho, amazon-redshift

I am getting the below error, while moving data from MySQL to redshift database.

Source data is :

```
id  emp_name    age city    update_date
a01 sarang      25  indore  2016/01/10 00:00:00.000
a02 shri        26  indore  2016/01/11 00:00:00.000
a03 chinu       27  indore  2016/01/12 00:00:00.000
a04 rohan       25  indore  2016/01/13 00:00:00.000
a05 manish      26  shajapur    2016/01/14 00:00:00.000
```

Table definition is :

```
CREATE TABLE CDC (
  id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  emp_name varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  age int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  update_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

Am unable to see any data type issues.

Comment: unable to find the error mentioned.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
CREATE TABLE CDC (
  id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  emp_name varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  age integer DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  update_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

As stated in the doc ([Redshift Data Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html)), the proper syntax for declaring integers is SMALLINT, INTEGER or BIGINT, depending on the value range of your field.

You might as well use timestamp for update_date if you want to keep the second precision.

Comment: the definition I have given is source DB, which is MySQL and not redshift.

Comment: So how do you transfer the data from mysql to redshift?

Comment: I am using Pentaho ETL for it.